# Wordpress Expert.Contact form in slider revolution slides

Tags: wordpress

Hi Everyone I want to add a Contact form 7 in My revolution Slider plugin.
Can Anyone help me how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not apply code to each slide. Apply code to Global layer. Follow the screenshot. Hope it will solve your issue.

[image: Click Here]